# How to log actual JAX-RS 2.0 client HTTP requests and responses

Tags: java, web-services, rest, logging, jax-rs

I'm writing a JAX-RS 2.0 client to send RESTful requests and process the returned responses.  To aid in debugging, I would like to log the actual HTTP request sent to the server and the HTTP response returned from the server.  Is there a way to do this using the JAX-RS 2.0 API (without depending on specific implementation classes)?

I've looked at JAX-RS 2.0 filtering (see  ["How to log request body in JAX-RS client"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30187514/how-to-log-request-body-in-jax-rs-client)); however the ClientResponseFilter and ClientResponseContext Interfaces are higher level abstractions and don't give access to the actual HTTP request and response sent over the socket connection.  I even briefly looked at JAX-WS logging (see [Log jax-ws http request and response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13285342/log-jax-ws-http-request-and-response)), but this seems to offer server logging rather than client logging.

Comment: You can get some ideas from this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38459381/1426227). Adapt the filter according to your needs.